# Reversing y axis in polaraxis plot

Tags: pgfplots, polarplot

I'm trying to reverse the y axis of my polaraxis plot while keeping the zero towards east. This is supposed to produce a clockwise polar plot.

However, the tick anchors are not mirrored in the correct way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{polaraxis}[
    y dir=reverse
]
\addplot table{
    0 1 
    30 2
    60 4
    90 6
    120 4
    };
\end{polaraxis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I get that fixed?
A similar problem is given in [Reverse xaxis on polar plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118100/reverse-xaxis-on-polar-plot)

Comment: [x tick label style={anchor=center}] doesn't exactly fix it, but at least it is consistent.  ]xticklabel shift=-2.5mm] has about the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `xticklabel style={anchor=180-\tick}` you can fix anchor of  `xticklabel` on this reversed y axis, to drive away tick labels from the center you can add `inner xsep=2mm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{polaraxis}[
    y dir=reverse,
    xticklabel style={anchor=180-\tick}]
\addplot table{
    0 1 
    30 2
    60 4
    90 6
    120 4
    };
\end{polaraxis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Short and simple, yet effective! Thanks a lot!